# Как сделать нажатый фильтр активным, а другие фильтры неактивными

Tags: javascript, reactjs

У меня есть компонент FilterBar

```
const FilterBar = ({filters}) => {    
const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false)

return (
    <div className="typeBar">
        {filters.length > 0 ? 
            filters.map(filter =>
                <div className={visible ? "typeBar__item tybeBar__active" :"typeBar__item"} key={filter.id} 
                onClick={() => {filter.func(); setVisible(!visible) }}
                >{filter.name}</div>

        )
        :
        <h1>no filter</h1>
        }
    </div>
)
}
```

Он отвечает за сортировку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хотела сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на определенный фильтр он становился активным(т.е. менял background). Только когда я нажимаю на один из фильтров, они все становятся активными.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне сделать так, чтобы цвет менял только один фильтр?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-chg9pt?file=src%2FApp.js можно вот так попробовать. А в примере у вас visible общий для всех div

Comment: Здравствуйте. Вообще, вместо visible лучше использовать что-то вроде activeFilter. Т.е., при нажатии у вас будет происходить setActiveFilter(filter.id). А уже потом проверяете activeFilter === filter.id и на основе этого применяет стили.